# Can I use SUMIFS to provide the sum of data from two different parameters?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I'm reporting on sales per product type, which I'm using a SUMIFS formula to pull the sum of sales monthly for the product type. But I want to add another sheet with the sum of sales monthly per item within the item type.

Can I use SUMIFS to look for all the product types in January, and then all the individual items within this range?

This is my SUMIFS for monthly :

```
=SUMIFS('All Sales'!$J$348:$J$1907,'All Sales'!$A$348:$A$1907,">="&'All Sales Chart'!B12,'All Sales'!$A$348:$A$1907,"<="&EOMONTH('All Sales Chart'!B12, 0))
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Some sample data would probably help. Your sum ranges and criteria ranges seem valid, and can pull your criteria from a different worksheet. So I'm not fully sure what you are asking. That's where a sample might help.

Comment: Basically the formula i pasted is pulling the sum of all sales in a given month. I want to add to that then pull the sum of sales per item within that month. Just adding a sample to OP

Comment: The image help. Show an expected result as well and someone might be able to suggest a formula

Comment: are you asking to return an array of values? With the right criterial setup, newer version of excel will spill the array.

Comment: What i'm hoping to achieve is something like what i've added to OP

Answer (score 0):

If your data is in cells A1:D13, looking just like your data shown above, and you use G2 to imput your desired month with H2 for inputting your desired item, the following formula would do the trick:

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D13,  B2:B13,  "="& G2,  C2:C13,"="& H2)
```

If you aren't looking to enter desired lookups and get results, but rather desire a table of all the possible combinations, the following will do that for you without having to figure out how to exclude things:

```
=SUMIFS(D2:D13,  B2:B13,  "="&LEFT(  UNIQUE(B2:B13  &"|"&  C2:C13),  3),
                 C2:C13,  "="&RIGHT(G5#,  LEN(UNIQUE(B2:B13  &"|"&  C2:C13))-4)  )
```

Since it only uses combinations your data actually contains, you don't find yourself using lists of all possiblities and excluding missing elements, or zeroing them. For example, "Feb" and "Item 3" do not exist. This way doesn't even bother with the combo, but a preset list pairing all months and all possible item numbers would include it and you'd have to handle that.

For the three columns such an output table would likely have, extract the part of the above formula that is the `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` clauses and fill your OUTPUT table's Month and Item columns with those results and the sum that calculates with the whole formula would be column 3.

Since you use three letter abbreviations for the date, the formula above is a little simpler as you KNOW the month takes three characters and don't need to, say, `FIND()` the `|` character and take everything to its left to get the month. Much easier! Ina ddition, you know the `|` is character four so you can use "4" in the `RIGHT()` fucntion insted of using `FIND()` in it. Again, much easier.

Downside? Well, depending upon use, your users might value having those lines with zeros, or blanks, to help in spotting products that are not selling. Well, ups and downs for everything, right? YOu have to select based upon need. Neither the inclusive or exclusive (above) methods are right or wrong in themselves, just in your use setting.

Last thought:  when combining cells for use like this, you can, of course, just use, say, `A2&B2` but oddities in the real-life contents could lead to false results. Largely that revolves around spaces and how the result can deceive Excel. Putting some not normally used character, like the `|`, in between helps keep those results from happening. This is especially important when these are used for comparisons, like here, rather than results.

Another "last thought"... if you use real dates, just formatting them for "mmm" to display as you  have them, you could wrap the portion of the formula above that is the `UNIQUE()` function and its contents with `SORT()` and your data table would need no sorting since the sorting would be done here. But with text etnries in the date column, "Jan" would sort after "Feb" and "Mar" which we usually don't want.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I've added what my end table would hopefully look like. Items down the A column, months across Row 1, date for # of sales in a cross-reference table.